# Null pointer exception on create() Android

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a method that I use to recieve some information. I send to this method one string (the server direction), and two strings that contains the user and the password, and I recieve an String[] with all the information, but I have a NullPointerException at

```
values = request("http://myIp/XXX/post.php?request=1", user, password);
```

line. The complete code is the next:

```
String[] values;

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_environment);   

    myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    user = myBundle.getString("user");
    password = myBundle.getString("password");

    values = request("http://myIp/XXX/post.php?request=1", user, password);  

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
}
```

The method is the next:

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public String[] request(String requesturl, String user, String password)
{
    String result[] = null; 

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(requesturl);

        String results = "";

        //Varibles POST
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));                        

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        response.getAllHeaders();
        response.getEntity();
        result[0] = "";                                                                         
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            results = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());           
            if(!results.equals("-1"))
            {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(results);

                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("edificios");

                int lengthJsonArr =jsonMainNode.length();
                for(int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);   
                    result[i] = jsonChildNode.optString("nombre"); 
                }
            }                 
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        result[0] = "error";
        return result;
    }
}
```

I recieved a NullPointerException on the "values=request("....");" line and I don't know why, because user and password have values and the other value is a string... What could be do?

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("null")` indicates you've decided to ignore a compiler warning about your problem. Remove that and fix the problem. Hint: `result` is not initialized. You should not catch `Exception`, at least not without logging/re-throwing.

Comment: I put the logcat now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared your `result` String array but did not initialize it.

Try this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public String[] request(String requesturl, String user, String password)
{
    String result[] = new String[ <Insert value> ];
    // Code...
}
```

Let me explain further to avoid downvotes. This is why I think this:

You first initialize the array to null, so it can't be used yet. Further down the line you have this statement `String results = ""` but your array is still `null`. Then you do this `result[0] = ""`, oh dear. That is where the `nullPointerException` comes from, I think.

You have to initialize your array and you are right if you say that you need to know the size of your array up front. Use the maximum value you expect for the size or, better yet, use a `list` and not an `array`.

Here is a nice source for the `list` datastructure: [List in Android Development](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html).

There is also a nice discussion about `list` versus `arrays` [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/221892/should-i-use-a-list-or-an-array), it is for C# but the principles remain more or less the same.

Comment: But I don't know the size of the String result[], I mean, if I use this I have to give to it a size and I don't know what size is it, isn't it?

Comment: @Imrik Then use a list.

Comment: @Imrik I have added two sources for you to explore, it should give you the solution you need.

Comment: Now I have the next error, I put the new logcat on my answer, I don't know what error is that, can you (or other) help me?

Comment: @Imrik That is great, you're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. I'm trying hard to build some rep on StackOverflow ;-).

Comment: @Imrik Try to solve the new problem yourself and if you open a new question if you really can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

`You got the exception because you are trying to access the first element of the`result`, which is not even initialized.`

So you need to initialize the array first and then use it

```
result = new String[<some size>];
```

If size of the array is not know in advance, then `ArrayList` can be a option for you.

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

usage

```
result.add(<some string value>);
```